# How to update the value of css id dynamically and ad class in active when clicked

Tags: angular

How to change the value of id dynamically. I am using for loop which has 10 items and I want to update the `id="Section1"` in such a way that for 2nd iteration it should be `Section2` and so on.

```
  <div *ngFor="let plan of allPlans; let i=index" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="Section1">
          <div class="pricing-bg pricing-img2">
            <h4>Total cost</h4>
            <figure><span>$</span><b>4</b></figure>
            <h3>per mail cost 0.5 ¢</h3>
            <button [routerLink]="userLoggedIn ? '/dashboard' : null" [attr.data-target]="modalId" data-toggle="modal" class="button button1 pricing-pad">GET STARTED</button>
          </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `[attr.id]="'Section' + i"`

Answer (score 0):

use data binding for id .

```
[id]="'Section'+i"
```

Comment: the index starts from 0 while section from 1

Comment: try plus one [id]="'Section'+i"